# how to pass multiple parameters in url when using vuejs

Tags: parameters, vue.js

Hey i am trying to pass two parameters in my url for a simple spa and the params values will be extracted from the url using an api and passed to the server here is the url:

http://localhost:8080/#/game/username/token

but when i am hitting the url its passing this in the network:

Request URL:http://localhost:8080/api/game/usernametoken

and hence it is not hitting the right api

**router**:

```
    {path:'game/:name/:token', name:'game', component: game  }
```

**front end:**

```
this.$http.get('/api/game/'+this.$route.params.name+this.$route.params.token)
```

**server-side:**

```
app.get('/api/game/:name/:token',function(req,res,err){
      var tex = {push:false};
    console.log("diplaying token from the server"+req.params.name+req.params.token)
    res.end(JSON.stringify(tex));

})
```

Comment: show some code please...

Comment: sorry i am editing and adding code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your get request should be

```
this.$http.get('/api/game/'+this.$route.params.name + '/' + this.$route.params.token)
```

You forgot the `'/'`